# Ruby, need to read the content of a file and split it on smaller new files

Tags: ruby, linux

I have a long file with tons of hostnames with options..

something like

```
hostname {
   option 1
   option 2
   option 3
}
```

the file has approximately 2000 hostnames. what I want to do in ruby is to:

open the file
start reading
when I get to a hostname create a file with that hostname
and put that same information from that hostname only then when it gets to } stop
and continue to the next hostname/repeat

Comment: show us what you've got. nobody will write you the whole thing.

Comment: You have explained what you need, now plz ask your question

Comment: hello, thanks for responding.. my question will be to have an example on how to go with this since im lost.. if it was just to grab one line then it will be easier.. but I need to grab blocks and make different files with each block.

Answer (score 1):

One way to make this work, if you know that a { or } will not be in an option would be to use the scan method with [multiline](http://doc.infosnel.nl/ruby_regular_expressions.html) mode on the regexp:

```
b.scan( /([^\{]*)(\{)([^\}]*\n)*(\})/m)
=> [["a ", "{", "\n b\n c \n d\n", "}"], 
    ["\nB ", "{", "\n 1\n 2\n 3\n", "}"]]
```

your re will need a bit of tweaking but it'll work, if you want to fit it all in memory for the parse. Writing to a file should be straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

For what you posted I guess something like this would do:

```
str = <<EOF
hostname1 {
  hi
}
hostname2 {
  how
}
hostname3 {
  are
}
EOF

hostnames = str.scan(/^\w+ {.*?}/m)
hostnames.each do |hostname|
    #here save it to a new file
    puts hostname
end
```

---

**EDIT**
Here goes a full example, it will read `hostnames.cfg` and save individual files on a folder called `hostnames`

**hostnames.cfg**

```
hostname1 {
  hi
}
hostname2 {
  how
}
hostname3 {
  are
}
```

**whatever.rb**

```
file = File.open('./hostnames.cfg', 'r')
content = file.readlines.join
file.close

hostnames = content.scan(/^\w+ {.*?}/m)
hostnames.each do |hostname|
    name = hostname.scan(/^\w+/m).first
    new = File.open("./hostnames/#{name}.cfg", "w+")
    new.write(hostname)
    new.close
end
```

Comment: Hello this is exactly what im looking for or similar.. but Im having an issue trying to read the whole file into memory to then parse the .scan on it.. you are using EOF im trying to use FILE.read(filename.cfg) when I use File.open then it will spit a ruby error about .scan because the file is already close Im guessing..

Comment: looks like I cant paste code here grgrgr this is what im doing:<pre><code>   `#!/usr/bin/env ruby

open("file.cfg") do |str|
   str.scan(/^\w+ {.*?}/m) do |hostname|
        puts hostname
   end
end`

Comment: The str you have above isn't a string, it's an open file. You can use IO.readlines(filename) to read all the lines in a file into an array. You can then call join('') on the result to get one big string.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
actual_host = nil
#~ inputfile = File.open(filename)
inputfile = DATA #Only thi stestcase

inputfile.each_line{|line|
  case line
    when /\A\s*(\S+)\s*\{/
      filename = "#{$1}.txt" #write to <<hostname>>.txt
      raise "File already exist" if File.exist?(filename)
      actual_host = File.new(filename, 'w')
    when /\A\s*\}/
      actual_host = nil
    else  #copy data, if inside a host file
      actual_host << line if actual_host
      #Alternative without leading/trailing spaces
      #~ actual_host << line.strip if actual_host
    end
}

inputfile.close

__END__
hostname {
   option 1
   option 2
   option 3
}
```

It parses line by line and starts a new file for each `hostname {` and close it at `}`. Everything in between is stored to a new file. if the target file already exists, the script stopps with an exception.